# Windows 8 Application Webview Login Screen

Tags: windows-8, webview, windows-store-apps

I'm having a problem with WebView. I have a webpage that you can access when only you are authenticated by entering username and password with an **ordinary** webbrowser such as **Chrome**. (*You know, a pop up windows appears, and you enter your credentials*). Just after entering your credentials, and when you call your website, you can display the contents. This webpage can be also displayed in company domain. Not accessible to publicity.

When I call this website in my windows 8 application in my company domain. Neither a page appears nor my credentials asked with any popup screen. How can I show **this login screen** as Chrome, Explorer does? How can I access this content or somehow get authenticated by entering my credentials?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you use cookies when you show your login?
 Cookies don't work in Store app.

I think you need to make a (WCF) service and call it in your windows store application.